# How can I pass in a variable defined in a class into a Rails form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

If I have a controller

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  vals = [...]

  def new
    ...
  end

  def create
    if save
      ...
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

how can I make the "vals" variable accessible to both methods? In my "new" view I want to use the "vals" variable for a drop-down menu, but rails is giving me errors. Of course, I could just copy the variable twice, but this solution is inelegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sebastion mentions a before_ hook / callback is one way to go about it, however as you mentioned it is for a dropdown menu, I am guessing it is a non-changing list, if so I would suggest perhaps using a Constant to define the values, perhaps in the model they are specific to, or if it is to be used in many places a PORO would do nicely to keep things DRY. This will then also allow you to easily access it anywhere, for example in models for a validation check, or to set the options of the dropdown menu in the view, or in the controller if you so wish:

```
class ExampleModel
  DROPDOWN_VALUES = [...].freeze

  validates :some_attr, inclusion: { in: DROPDOWN_VALUES } 
end

class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def new
    # can call ExampleModel::DROPDOWN_VALUES here
  end

  def create
    # also here, anywhere actually
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `before_*` callback, e.g a `before_action`, this way you sets your vals variable as an instance one and make it to be available for your both new and create methods, something like:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_vals, only: [:new, :create]

  def new
    ...
    # @vals is available here
  end

  def create
    if save
      ...
      # and here
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private 

  def set_vals
    @vals = [...]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

A different way  from the ones before  (although probably just having the instance method is preferred as in Sebastian's solution) is, take advantage of the fact that functions and local variables are called in the same way in ruby and just write:

```
 def vals
   @vals ||= [...]
 end
```

and you should be able to access it on the controllers (not the views). If you want it on your views as well you can call at the beginning of the controller

```
 helper_method :vals
```

If you want to be able to modify vals using vals="some value"

```
def vals= vals_value
  @vals = vals_value
end
```

Take into account that probably using the intance variable as in Sebastian's solution is preferred, but if you, for whatever reason, are settled on being able to call "vals" instead of "@vals" on the view (for example if you are using send or try), then this should be able to do it for you.

Answer (score -1):

Define in corresponding `model`

Eg :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  TYPES = %w{ type1 type2 type3 }

end
```

and use in ur form like

```
User::TYPES

=> ["type1", "type2", "type3"]
```

You can reuse this anywhere in the application.

Comment: How is that any different to my answer already provided? You have given nothing new to the question, just provided the exact same solution as an answer already given an hour before...

Comment: I think you edited ur answer and I posted my views how to use directly without passing into variable. So just chill don't get hyper. :)

Comment: anser hasn't been edited, chilled don't worry, just pointing out the fact that nothing new at all has been added through this answer, and if everyone just adds the same answers everywhere, we are gona have a bad time as a community.